# Maven generated source folder document

Tags: maven, code-generation

I saw lots of code generation plugins in Maven put generated code in `target/generated-source/*plugin-name*` directory. But I didn't find it documented anywhere in Maven standard directory layout. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Where is it documented in Maven? Or it's just a convention that everyone follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not described as part of the standard directory layout, since these files are generated( hence, they end up in the target/ directory). By the `target/generated-source/plugin-name` convention the plugin-writer is pretty sure it won't clash with generated sources of other plugins. The plugin-writer is also responsible for binding this source folder to the Maven project. 
As a user you shouldn't notice much of it.